# Import Namespace System.Query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am trying to load Linq on my .Net 3.5 enabled web server by adding the following to my .aspx page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Query" %>
```

However, this fails and tells me it cannot find the namespace.

> The type or namespace name 'Query' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

I have also tried with no luck:

- `System.Data.Linq`
- `System.Linq`
- `System.Xml.Linq`

I believe that .Net 3.5 is working because `var hello = "Hello World"` seems to work.

Can anyone help please?

PS: I just want to clarify that I don't use Visual Studio, I simply have a [Text Editor](http://www.ultraedit.com/) and write my code directly into .aspx files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have version 2 selected in IIS and I

Well, surely that's your problem?  Select 3.5.

Actually, here's the real info:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What does the  part of your web.config file look like?

Here's what it looks like for a brand new ASP.NET 3.5 project made with Visual Studio 2008:

```
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer :) I needed to add the following to my web.config:

```
<assemblies>  
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>  
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>  
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>  
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>  
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
```

Then I could add the following to my code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

@Will,

Thanks for your help. I have accepted one of your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project is set to target 3.5, and not 2.0.

As others have said, your 'var' test is a test of C#3 (i.e. VS2008), not the 3.5 framework.

If you set the project framework target settings properly, you should not expect to need to manually add dll references at this point.

Comment: Hi Will, I'm not using VS. Is there any other way I can confirm if 3.5 is installed correctly?

Comment: What version of the framework have you selected on the ASP.NET tab in IIS?

Comment: I have version 2 selected in IIS and my web.config shows `Version=2.0.0.0`. Help :(

Answer (score 0):

The `var hello` stuff is compiler magic and will work without Linq.

Try adding a reference to `System.Core`

---

Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant add `System.Core` to the web project's references, not to the page.

The `Import` on the page are basically just using statements, allowing you to skip the namespace on the page.

Comment: Hi Keith, adding: <%@ Import Namespace="System.Core" %> failed to work and showed the same error message :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Keith was talking about adding a DLL reference, rather than another import. To be honest, I would suggest you start with Visual Studio (one of the free versions), as it will finesse this sort of stuff for you until you're a bit more up-to-speed with .NET development.

Comment: Yup, I have gone through those step. Like I said, I believe 3.5 is working because the syntax var string = "hello"; works because this is a new feature of .Net 3.5. I'm completely at a loss now. PS: Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: *`var string = "hello";` works because this is a new feature of .Net 3.5.* As at least two people have already tried to tell you in here, this is **NOT A FEATURE OF .NET 3.5** It's a feature of C#3, which is the version of the language supported by the compiler that comes with VS2008. I find it hard to believe you've read and comprehended that Hanselman article, which seems to cover exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The csproj file might be missing the System.Core reference.
Look for a line in the csproj file like this:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
```

And add a line below it like this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
```